# Use Rolle to determine the number of possible solution of $f(x) = \sin x + x + 1$

Tags: functions, rolles-theorem

Good morning. I've found an exercise that require to find the **number** of possible solutions of the equation $f(x) = \sin x +x + 1$ in $[0, 2\pi]$ using Rolle's theorem.
How should I proceed? I know that the theorem ask for the function to be continuous in $[a, b]$, to be differentiable in $(a, b)$ and that $f(a) = f(b)$. 
$f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable but $f(0) = 1$ and $f(2\pi) = 1 + 2\pi$. How can I go on from here? Should I assume that, since i cannot use Rolle, I'm sure that there cannot be more than one solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "solutions" of $f(x)$?

Comment: I fail to see how Rolle's theorem can be useful here, as it allows you to determine zeroes of *the derivative*.

Comment: By solutions I mean that I need to find the zeros of f.
Also, I've asked about Rolle's theorem cause it was asked to do it that way in the exam but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're asking about the zeroes of $f$. We have $\sin(x)+1\geq 0$ for all $x$. If $x>0$, then $f(x)>0$ so there are no positive zeroes. It remains to check that $f(0)=1\ne 0$.